# Cookies aren't working

Tags: php, cookies

I tried to do use cookies to remember login information but the cookies never seemed to "take" as it were.  Here's the initial login script:

```
//try to login using cookies, but first make sure it doesn't have a $_SESSION variable for it
if (!(isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE["login"])) {
        //try to login using cookie
        $query = "select from cookie_users where uniqueid = '".$_COOKIE["login"]."')";
        $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows>0) {
            $result->fetch_assoc();
            $result['username'] = $username;
            $result['password'] = $password;
            //try to login using password and username from cookie database
            $query = "select * from authorized_users where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($query);
            if ($result->num_rows>0) {
                $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    // if the user has just tried to log in
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $db_conn=new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Connection to database failed: '.mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit;
    }
    $query = 'select * from authorized_users '."where name='$userid' "."and password=sha1('$password')";

    $result = $db_conn->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        //if they are in the database, register the user id
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $userid;
        //set up cookie
        setcookie("login", $uniqueid, time()*60*60*24*14);
        $query = "insert into cookie_users values ('".$userid."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$uniqueid."')";
        $result = $db_conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not update cookie in database';
        }
    }
    $db_conn->close();
}
```

Members only content:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user'] {
echo "members only content goes here";
} else {
echo "you need to login"; }
```

The sessions and login scripts work just fine.  If they login directly using the login page, it shows up.  If they go to another page and then come back, it still works; so that leaves me to believe that the sessions work just fine.  However, if you close down the browser and come back, it doesn't register.  If something's messed up with the script, please let me know.  Either way, I did a test script and not even that works.  Here it is:

```
<?php

setcookie("test", "the test is good", time()*60*60);

?>

<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["test"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

So I think I'm missing something fundamental.  Sorry if the answer is painfully obvious, cookies are new to me.  Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Comment: But you may benefit from a a more descriptive title .. :)

Comment: Do you have your browser set to some privacy mode where all cookies are deleted on close?

Comment: Also, `time() * 60 * 60` might overflow or something. Use `time() + (60 * 60)` instead.

Comment: You are forgetting to escape all your database parameters. Your code as shown is trivially hackable.

Comment: Arxanas - if I was to close the browser, it would then echo the cookie content???

Comment: This code is very hard to follow and full of potential hazards. You are connecting to the database multiple times and assigning variable which go nowhere, not to mention using confusing variable names.

Nevertheless I think the critical problem is that you're not defining $uniqueid anywhere

Comment: I know I should escape the database parameters, this code won't ever go live.  I was just testing the idea of using cookies with the uniqueid to log somebody in automatically

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the part of the code that shows what uniqueid is, but rest assured there is a uniqueid created.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this line:

```
setcookie("login", $uniqueid, time()*60*60*24*14);
```

Here, you're multiplying the time instead of adding to it. You've multiplied it by enough to *exceed the* `MAX_INT` *size* (see [Y2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)). For whatever reason, Apache (at least, on my system) will ignore that header and the browser will then keep it only for the length of the session. Fortunately, you can fix the problem fairly simply:

```
setcookie("login", $uniqueid, time() + 60*60*24*14); // Adding two weeks, not multipying by >9000
```

Comment: Thank you arxanas.  I'll fix it.